# $PATH is filled with duplicates

Tags: bash, terminal, environment-variables

I recently started configuring a OSX 10.7 environment for development. I've installed HomeBrew, and added the following to my `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```

Everything is working great except when I `echo $PATH` I get the following string of duplicates:
              `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin`

To make it more readable, these are all the paths:

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
~/bin:/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
~/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
usr/local/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/local/git/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/X11/bin
```

I don't think I've made any changes to path besides the single line in my `.bash_profile`. What is the best way for me to pair down those duplicates? Is there a way to hunt down which files are modifying my path and try to eliminate them?

Comment: Anything in `/etc/paths.d/`? Any other bash configuration files?

Comment: I really wouldn't worry about it. Bash will only do a single lookup for a command name once during a session; afterwards, it stores the command's full path in an internal hash table. You will probably spend far more time looking for the source of the duplicates than bash will ever, cumulatively, spend searching for the location of executables in `PATH` directories.

Comment: @slhck `/etc/paths.d` has one file with the line `/usr/X11/bin
` in it. I haven't made any other bash configuration files that I know of (I only have .bash_profile in ~)

Comment: See: https://superuser.com/questions/1216649/why-is-my-bash-profile-showing-duplicated-entries, where a (partial) list of places to look for duplicates is given.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Having made my comment, here are some suggestions for pruning `$PATH` anyway.

Looking at your path, it appears that `.bash_profile` is being executed twice, or the modification made in `.bash_profile` is duplicated elsewhere.

There are 7 duplicate additions of '/usr/local/git/bin' and 'use/local/bin' [sic], followed by 5 more copies of '/usr/local/git/bin'. Depending on how `git` is installed, you may be able to query your package manager about what files were installed with `git`; there could be some configuration files or modified system files that affect `PATH`.

Put `set -x` at the very top of your `.bash_login`, then start a new login shell. You should get a lot of output that shows exactly what `bash` is doing on startup, which should help you figure out where `PATH` is being modified. You can remove `set -x` once you figure it out or give up. If you don't find anything, you could also add it to the beginning of `/etc/profile` to trace what the system does before your own `.bash_profile` is processed.

Comment: I used set -x, saw that the only major modification to PATH was in my .bash_profile and removed that line. Now my path is much cleaner (don't know how that line managed to wreak so much havoc). Thanks so much for the answer @chepner!

Comment: Can I configure the output of `set -x` to a log file?

Comment: `bash` will write to whatever file descriptor is found in `BASH_XTRACEFD`, if defined. Something like `exec {BASH_XTRACEFD}> log.txt` will redirect the trace output to `log.txt`  (using the redirection operator that automatically allocates a file descriptor and assigns it to a given name).

Answer (score 9):

I ran [Ryan Thompson's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149054/154067) from the command line.
It removed all the duplicates for me, without changing the order, and without leaving a trailing `:`

```
PATH="$(perl -e 'print join(":", grep { not $seen{$_}++ } split(/:/, $ENV{PATH}))')"
```

In addition to the convenient 1-liner above, Ryan shares the (more 
 structured) script he uses in his `config` to de-duplicate  other variables *and*  the `PATH`.

([See his Unix & Linux post for more details](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/149054/154067))

Comment: I can't get this fix to persist. It does clean duplicates from `$PATH`, but if I open a new Ubuntu WSL2 command prompt window, my `$PATH` is back to having duplicates. How can I make this permanent?

Answer (score 3):

I added this to my $HOME/.bashrc (you should also be able to add it to .bash_profile instead if you wish) to remove duplicate entries from the $PATH. I've only tested on linux but should also work on mac. It should be added after the initial export PATH.

```
export PATH=$(echo $PATH | awk -F: '
{ for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) arr[$i]; }
END { for (i in arr) printf "%s:" , i; printf "\n"; } ')
```

Comment: This changes the order of entries in PATH.  **Dangerous!!**

Answer (score 0):

An installation of `git` modified your `.bash_profile` without serious preliminary check. This installer corrupted it (apparently 12 times).
Use the receipe suggested by [rash](https://superuser.com/a/504987/233562), but just once to define the correct minimal PATH to include back in your `.bash_profile`.

You don't need to initialize your PATH in your `.bashrc`. This initialisation script is reserved to configuration which have to change with each level of shell, for example a prompt, a position, a color, but not a PATH.